# How do I have the data read from the excel file save to a new class each time it runs

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hello I have read the data on an excel file and then I have that data being stored into an Array list. I want the arraylist to be stored in another class on eclipse every time I run the program with different files. So I will have another class in my package holding all of these arrays. Sorry if I'm not explaining well enough, but I want to run this program and get a new arraylist each time stored on another file in the package.

```
package Experiment1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcel {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/myfile"));

    //create workbook instance that refers to .xlsx file
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);


    //create a sheet object to retrieve the sheet
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    //this is for evaluate the cell type
    FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();


    //int rowStart = Math.min(1, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
    //int rowEnd = Math.max(64, sheet.getLastRowNum());



    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

    for(Row row : sheet){

        for(Cell cell : row){


            switch(formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType())
            {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                list.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());

                break;

            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

                break;
            }
        }

        /*for(int i = 0; i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
        */

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Btw the second for loop where I'm printing it to screen irrelevant, should have commented that out.

Comment: "in a separate class", what do you mean! in another XSSFSheet , or inside another XSSFWorkbook ? it is not clear!

Comment: I edited the question..hopefully this makes sense now? basically I want to read multiple files and have there data stored into an arraylist, but I need those arraylists in a seperate class within the package.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have understood what you mean.
The job is to store in a file inside the same package your `ArrayList<Double> list`.

Learn about [Serialization in Java (IBM)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things1/) and [its secrets (Oracle...)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html).

Declare your class with `implements Serializable`, add a generated unique identifier for object serialization, add some essential stuff like `toString()`, `hashCode()`, etc. methods...

And now you will be able to do what you need with the `list.serialize()` method or with `InputStream` and `OutputStream` like in the docs.

I have just found something you will enjoy [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-serialize-arraylist-in-java/) :

**Serialization:**

```
package beginnersbook.com;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class ArrayListSerialization {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
       al.add("Hello");
       al.add("Hi");
       al.add("Howdy");

       try {
           FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("myfile");
           ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
           oos.writeObject(al);
           oos.close();
           fos.close();
       } catch(IOException ioe) {
           ioe.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

**Deserialization :**

```
package beginnersbook.com;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class DeSerializationClass  {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myfile");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            arraylist = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
         } catch(IOException ioe) {
             ioe.printStackTrace();
             return; 
         } catch(ClassNotFoundException c) {
             System.out.println("Class not found");
             c.printStackTrace();
             return;
          }
        for(String tmp: arraylist) {
            System.out.println(tmp);
        }
   }
}
```